# Correct permissions when cloning a git repo on linux/ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I am cloning a repo containing NodeJs code in Ubuntu, however after calling `git clone`, I call `ls -l` to check the permissions, all my files only have `-rw-------` (600) permissions. When I try to build the app, I get some weird permission errors so I think the reason is that my folders don't have the proper permissions.

If I do `chmod -R` to change permissions, then all my files are shown as modified in git, so I think I am doing something wrong but don't have a clue what it is.

What should be the correct permissions here?

Comment: Please [edit] and show your full `chmod` command. I suspect you added `+x` to all files so Git is rightly considered the files changed (Git stores the executable attribute).

Comment: @phd, yes well I wanted to just add all permissions to see if it would solve my build problems. But obviously I don't want to do this every time because I don't have to do it on another machine. I noticed I have `umask 022` in `/etc/profile`, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I don't see any problem with `umask 022`; check your current mask with bare command `umask`. Run `git reset --hard HEAD` to undo (to restore) permissions. `chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX .` to set standard permissions; please note uppercase `X` (this also sets permissions inside `.git/objects/`; if that's not desireable do `find .git/objects -type f -exec chmod a=r '{}' \+` — that are standard Git permissions for files in `.git/objects/` to signify Git object are read-only).